# Cant reach 3rd Party App from Docker container

Tags: docker, network-programming, docker-swarm

I have an application where I have multiple instances of container talking with each other and another external application. My external application is on `10.139.74.xxx` and my application is on `10.139.75.xxx`. I am able to reach the external application from my application server but I am not able to reach the external application from within my docker container. I am using REST API calls on the external application form my docker containers. Please help me.

Comment: please specify how you want to reach them or what you already tried to reach them in detail.

Comment: I need to execute Rest based API's on the 3rd party applciation

Comment: could you give some examples to work with?

Comment: lets say for example - my exApp is my external application @ 10.139.75.111
I have C1 and C2 containers in 1 server @ 10.139.74.112
I can ping or execute API call on exApp from the linux server @ 10.139.74.112 But cant execute my APIs from within C1 and C2